# How to remove character from struts2 property tag

Tags: java, struts2

```
I want to remove first char from property tag in struts2 ex **<property value="name">** which   display name #abhijit but I  want to remove first char from that value.
```

I appended the String to that    special character in action class.
   I want pass that value as request parameter to get all record which
  match with  value.but due to that special character i am not geting the value in action class.
  here is action class code.

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) ActionContext.getContext()
             .get(ServletActionContext.HTTP_REQUEST);
            try {
                request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String tagname=request.getParameter("name");
            System.out.println("tag to search:"+tagname);
```

on Console

tag to search:

Comment: http://localhost:8080/project/result?name=#newone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid the first character, you could use String substring method and get the rest of the string value like below:

```
String tagWithoutFirstChar = tagname.subString(1);
```

Or use struts setProperty like:

```
<s:property value="tagname.substring(1)" />
```